# Getting different angles of projection at different coordinates of projectile

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, projectile, geometry

I have been confused about this question on projectile motion for a while, and although I have managed to get solutions, I have not seen a resolution of my confusion. The question is:

The horizontal and the vertical displacements of a projectile varies with time $t$ (in seconds) as
$$x=10\,t\,\sqrt3\tag{1}$$
$$y=10\,t-t^2\tag{2}$$

The obvious way to solve it would be to differentiate Equation (2) and find out time for maximum height, which would be 5 seconds. Plugging $t=5\,\text s$ in Equation (2) would give us $25\,\text m$ as the answer. However I decided to dig deeper into the problem and encountered some inconsistencies.

If we take a look at the equation of trajectory for a projectile,
$$y=x\tan\vartheta-\frac{gx^2}{2u^2\cos^2\vartheta}\tag{3}$$

And subsequently plug in coordinates of the given projectile at different times, we get different values of $\tan\vartheta$.

For example, if we use substitute $(100\sqrt3,0)\ @\ t=10\,\text s$ into Equation (3), we get $\tan\vartheta=5/\sqrt3$.

At $t=5\,\text s,$ substituting $(50\sqrt3,25)$ gives us $\tan\vartheta=\sqrt3$.

Also, if we analyse a bit more here, we can obtain $u\sin\vartheta=10\sqrt3\tan\vartheta=30\,\text{m/s}$.

Now, we know, maximum height is obtained at $t=u\sin\vartheta/g$. Putting values we get $t=3\,\text s,$ but earlier we have literally obtained $\tan\vartheta$ by substituting coördinates for maximum height at $t=5\,\text s$ into Equation (3), so why does the equation now give us another value of time for maximum height? So here we run into a contradiction within a case as well.

I cannot think of a reason why this is happening because the coördinates are obtained from a unique projectile so there should be no reason why different angles of projection are being obtained.

There must be some mistake in my methods due to which I am running into such contradictions.

Comment: Please use mathjax for formatting. Also, what is the initial velocity of the projectile?

Comment: Differentiating twice (ii), we get $a≠-g$.

Comment: Please see [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)
on how to use MathJax.
It's really unclear how to interpret some of the expressions you wrote

Comment: Equation (2) is not correct, it should be $y=10\,t-\frac g2\,t^2$

Answer (score 0):

You are simply having a lot of internal inconsistencies, even before the massive conceptual mistake in how the equations are to be used. I know you are not used to the algebra and want to substitute numbers in, but if you want to do that, you have to be internally consistent with how you do this.

First of all, you should be having an initial speed $u=20\,\text{m/s}$ at an angle of $\vartheta=30^\circ$ above the horizontal, so that your initial velocity is $(u\cos\vartheta,u\sin\vartheta)=(10\sqrt3,10)\,\text{m/s}$, and this is a projectile in free fall, so that $g\approx10\,\text{m/s}^2$. Actually, this nice value is part and parcel of why it is so easy for you to make a mistake—if you had used $g=9.81\,\text{m/s}^2,$ then you might have a much better chance of catching your own mistake by yourself.
$$x=ut\cos\vartheta=10\,t\,\sqrt3\tag{1'}$$
$$y=ut\sin\vartheta-\frac12gt^2=10\,t-5\,t^2\tag{2'}$$
If you compare my Equation (2') with your Equation (2), you will see that you have totally missed out the $\frac12g,$ and that is fatal, because then you cannot use any of the standard formulæ for projectile motion. That renders most of the other stuff that you wanted to do, immediately wrong to do.

Equation (3) is obtained by using Equation (1') to get $t=x/u\cos\vartheta$ and substitute into Equation (2')
$$y=u\frac x{u\cos\vartheta}\sin\vartheta-\frac12g\left(\frac x{u\cos\vartheta}\right)^2\tag{3'}$$
which you should be able to see, is the same as what you have, or quoted.

---

The rest of this is just going to be numerical substitutions to make you happy.

Differentiating Equation (2'), we find $t_\text{max}=u\sin\vartheta/g$ as you quoted, but this is now $@\ t_\text{max}=1,\ (x,y_\text{max})=(10\sqrt3,5)\,\text m$ where, upon substitution, gets $\tan\vartheta=1/\sqrt3$

If we now try $t=2\,\text s$ which is @ $(x,y)=(20\sqrt3,0)\,\text m,$ then we again get $\tan\vartheta=1/\sqrt3$, and all is fine.

There is no possibility of contradictions in the first place.

Nobody uses the equations to find $\tan\vartheta$ in the first place. You would already have had enough stuff given to you as to find it earlier. Not that you are disallowed to do so, just that it is going against the logical flow. But mathematics does allow you to do it anyway, and you can now see that everything is consistent.

Answer (score 0):

general case

$$x=u\,\cos(\vartheta)\,t\\
y=u\,\sin(\vartheta)\,t-\frac g2\,t^2$$

solve those 2 equations for y and t you obtain

$$y=x\tan\vartheta-\frac{gx^2}{2u^2\cos^2\vartheta}\\
t=\frac{x}{u\,\cos(\vartheta)}$$

your data

$$x=10\,\sqrt{3}\,t_n\\
y_n=10\,t-\frac g2 t_n^2$$

$\Rightarrow$

$$y_n=\frac 13\,x\sqrt {3}-{\frac {1}{600}}\,g{x}^{2}\\
t_n=\frac {1}{30}\,x\sqrt {3}$$

from here,  with $~y=y_n\quad,t=t_n~$
you obtain $u=20~[m/s],\vartheta=\frac \pi 6$

**Consistency**

with
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=0\quad,\Rightarrow\\
x_m=\frac{u^2\,\sin(2\vartheta)}{2g}\quad,t_m=\frac{x_m}{u\cos(\vartheta)}=\frac{10}{g}$$

with

$$\frac{dy_n}{dx_n}=0\quad,\Rightarrow\\
x_m=\frac{100\sqrt{3}}{g}\quad,t_m=\frac {1}{30}\,x_m\sqrt {3}=\frac{10}{g}$$

**notice**

your equation (2) is not correct !